# Replace RegEx pattern between two words within a single line

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to find all instances where one or more capitalized words followed by a colon ":" occurs between the strings "START:" and "END:". Then I want to add a period before each instance.

> **Example Input:**
>
> I want to test what happens if there is information before the header
>   I am looking for. Thus Here We Lie: And end. START: Now we see all the
>   important information that we have Along With: a bunch of Strange:
>   headers. I want to highlight all of the Headers: and add periods
>   before them to separate the information into different Sentences: Now
>   I can stop because I hit the end header. END: More information after
>   that I do Not Want To: capture. The End.
>
> **Desired Output:**
>
> I want to test what happens if there is information before the header
>   I am looking for. Thus Here We Lie: And end. START: Now we see all the
>   important information that we have . Along With: a bunch of . Strange:
>   headers. I want to highlight all of the . Headers: and add periods
>   before them to separate the information into different . Sentences:
>   Now I can stop because I hit the end header. END: More information
>   after that I do Not Want To: capture. The End.

[image]

The following code will add the period before each of the headers. The part that I am struggling with is confining the replacement to be ***between*** the strings "START:" and "END:". Right now it is adding the periods everywhere.

`sed -r "s/(\b(.?[[:upper:]]\w+)++:)/. \1/g" TestData.txt`

I have tried looking through the solutions that have been proposed previously, but none are working for me, and I think it might have to do with the fact that all of the data is ***within a single line*** rather than over multiple lines.

So in all reality, my datafile looks like this:

```
I want to test what happens if there is information before the header I am looking for. Thus Here We Lie: And end. START: Now we see all the important information that we have Along With: a bunch of Strange: headers. I want to highlight all of the Headers: and add periods before them to separate the information into different Sentences: Now I can stop because I hit the end header. END: More information after that I do Not Want To: capture. The End.
```

**EDIT 1: Fixed the reality string**

Comment: In your last string, the reality string, there are some periods which are not in the first quoted "Example Input" like " . Along With: a bunch of . Strange:"  Those two inner periods are or aren't in the actual input?

Comment: If those inner periods do exist you could use (?:(\s+\.*\s+)(\w+)) and replace with . \2 to solve your problem.  https://regex101.com/r/Cn1mW2/1

Comment: @Mark I have adjusted the reality string so that it is the same as the input string. My apologies; I must have copied & pasted the wrong string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use and have GNU `awk` installed, you can use this as an alternate to `sed`. The `\y` is the word boundary equivalent of `\b` in `sed` and `&` is the matched captured group in the context of `awk`.

```
gawk 'match($0, /(.+)START(.+)END(.+)/, arr){gsub(/(\y(.?[[:upper:]]\w+)++:)/,".&",arr[2]); print arr[1] "START"arr[2]"END" arr[3] }' file
```